# How can i see If an object is destroyed in a DLL without using Visual Studio

Tags: dll, vb6, monitoring

The main software that we built is built using VB6 (old school, I know). We're having some problem for viewing a report using ActiveReports. We did many Debug DLLs and were unable to find why the problem happen. Note that restarting the server solves the issue, which brings us to think that the problem is resource related.

Is there a way I can see how much memory is being used by a DLL? I would like to see if an object in that dll might not be released correctly.

I tried using the performance monitor, but this is not as precise as needed.

Is there anything i could use to monitor a Dll's usage?

Comment: try any heap and stack monitor

Comment: talking about stack monitors, how should i use these? Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are just doing it the hard way and monitoring a server running multiple instances of the DLL.